# How to reference external assemblies in WinRT XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to add a reference to an external assembly inside XAML
the syntax is the following:

```
xmlns:my_namespace="using:CompanyName.AssemblyName"
```

The problem is that the actual class I'd like to use resides under `CompanyName.AssemblyName.InnerName` namespace.

What's the appropriate way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
xmlns:my="using:CompanyName.AssemblyName.InnerName"
```

Comment: It should find the actual assembly automatically, so just specifying the namespace of the class you want to use should be enough.

Comment: I see the auto-completion on namespace when typing it in XAML
yet the type I'm trying to reference isn't found
<my:MyType /> 
results in 'The name MyType does not exist in the namespace 'my'. Any thoughts? 
P.S. Cleaned and rebuilt the solution. Has had no impact.

Comment: James McNellis [said something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240426/wp8-cant-consume-a-native-component/13240813#13240813) about the required assembly name format being a prefix of your namespace ("CompanyName.AssemblyName" in your scenario). Otherwise - what is the language you use in your external assembly? Is the class public and sealed?