# Can't load a native DLL

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

It's a follow-up from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240426/wp8-cant-consume-a-native-component).

Windows Phone 8 C# project (MyApp), migrated from WP7.1. I've added a native Windows Runtime component library (AppLib) to the solution, created a reference. There's a public sealed ref class (MyClass) in it. There's a reference to it in the C# code (in `OnLoaded` of the main XAML page). The whole thing builds - meaning the metadata of the component is being generated.

When I'm trying to run on the emulator, the project fails with the exception or type `BadImageFormatException` with the following message:

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

The error typically pops up when you try to mix CPU types in .NET.

The active platform is "Mixed platforms". In the Configuration Manager, it's configured to build `MyApp` for "x86" and `AppLib` for "Win32". In a vanilla freshly generated project that runs fine, the config is identical.

Question - what's wrong with that configuration? What do I need to check?

EDIT: I've added a second, blank C++ library to the solution - `TestLib`. This one loads and works as expected.

EDIT2: excluded everything from build in AppLib - it works. Now I'll be adding lines one by one, see which one causes the issue...

Comment: Is this a *Windows Phone* WinRT component?

Comment: The project type of the library is "Windows Phone Runtime Component". The property sheet under General says "Windows Phone 8.0 (v110)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally my fault. When I changed the namespace of AppLib (see the linked question), I've left one little declaration in the library in a `MyApp` namespace.

The error is still misleading. I'd delete the question, but since the error message is sure to send someone on a wild goose chase with build CPU type and whatnot, let it remain.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't a Windows Phone library be built for ARM in most cases? Have you had a chance to watch the "[Windows Phone 8: Using C++ in your Applications](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-049)" session from last week's [//Build/](http://www.buildwindows.com/) conference? That might include some answers.

Comment: The WP8 emulator is x86, not ARM. There's another C#/C++ solution that works, with an identical configuration (Win32 and x86).

Comment: Perhaps the native dll references a library that is of different format?

Comment: I didn't add any references to the library except what was there at project creation time. I did add a bunch of sources though. But they refer to nothing except vanilla RTL.